# Is it possible to display the content along with spacing and bold?

Tags: php, html, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am using the below code for importing the excel sheet and inserting the data into the database and it's working. There is no issue with it.

Now, I have a column name called `content`. I am uploading the content in it. so below is the example of the content.

[image]

Now after importing the data I am getting the output like. so it's removing the strong part and spacing etc.

[image]

I am using the rich text editor and I am displaying the data in it.

```
function listImport($pdo){
if($_FILES["emplist"]["name"] != '')
{
   $allowed_extension = array('csv');
   $file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["emplist"]["name"]);
   $file_extension = end($file_array);

   if(in_array($file_extension, $allowed_extension))
   {
    $file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['emplist']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
    $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
    $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);

    unlink($file_name);

  $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();

    $isheader = 0;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {

    if($isheader > 0) {

     $insert_data = array(
      ':name'  => $row[0],
      ':email'  => $row[1],
      ':content'  => $row[2]
     );

     $query = "INSERT INTO `employee`(`name`, `email`, `content`) VALUES (:name,:email,:content)";

     $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute($insert_data);
         } 
         else { 

          $isheader = 1; 
        }
    } // foreach
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Data Imported Successfully</div>';

   } //in_array

   else
   {
    $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .csv file allowed</div>';
   }

}
else
{
 $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Select File</div>';
}

echo $message;

}
```